# WiX -- Installing files to system drive

Tags: wix

I'm working on an installer that drops some files into another application that keeps its files at [SystemDrive]\appName.  The installer is only used in internal automation, so it's fine if it doesn't consider other install locations.

I've found that by default WiX sets the target directory to the drive with the most free space.  What's the best way to specify a certain directory in the system drive instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the value of rootdrive to the drive you want

```
<CustomAction Id='SetRootDrive' Property='ROOTDRIVE' Value='[%SystemDrive]\'/>
```

System drive will be by default the default drive used by OS

**Added code to call 'SetRootDrive' action:**
You need to call it from InstallUISequence

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Show Dialog="MyWelcomeDlg" Before="CostFinalize">NOT Installed</Show>
  <!-- App search is what does FindInstallLocation, and it is dependent on FindRelatedProducts -->
  <AppSearch After="FindRelatedProducts"/>
  <Custom Action="SetRootDrive" Before="CostInitialize"></Custom>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Comment: When does this custom action need to be scheduled?  I have it set to before Cost Initialize and it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: I have added the call in my answer

Comment: You should also consider scheduling this action in [`InstallExecuteSequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369500.aspx) sequence so that it would still work when you run you installation with basic or no UI.

Comment: You can use [`WindowsVolume`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372817.aspx) property [as suggested by Bob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986252/wix-installing-files-to-system-drive/6987063#6987063) instead of environment variable. This way I see no need for custom action at all.

Answer (score 3):

MSI already gives you the value in the WindowsVolume property. Use that as the parent Directory/@Id.