# WiX installs the application on default drive (C:\) in-spite of mentioning the drive on which it should install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, wix

We have WiX installer which should do the installation of the msi into "D:\" drive , but on some target machines it installs the application on the drive which has more space. 
i.e If "C:" has more space installation will be done in "C:\".
Although on the target machines which have more D:\ drive space , application gets installed on D:.

In our Directory Structure Definition we have used [INSTALLFOLDER] and value for ID=TARGETDIR is "D:\"

Could anyone guide me what needs to be done to make the installation on D:\ only

Comment: Please have a look at this similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986252/wix-installing-files-to-system-drive and give the value 'D:\' to test.

Comment: Is my solution was helpful for you? if yes please mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set the property RootDrive.

```
<Property Id="ROOTDRIVE" Value="D:\"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i just found an answer to my own question,i had written a custom Action under      as below:

```
<InstallUISequence>
   <Custom Action="SetRootDrive" Before="CostInitialize" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

to solve the issue i removed it from UIsequence and added it under      as below:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <WriteEnvironmentStrings>ENABLEEV=1</WriteEnvironmentStrings>
   <Custom Action="SetRootDrive" Before="CostInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```